# How to record code execution timings for multiple functions as a pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple functions, where each function is designed to perform a particular task. For the sake of an example, suppose I want to prepare lunch. Possible functions for this task can be, `collect_vege_images()` `remove_duplicates()` and `count_veges_in_multiple_plates()`.

**Problem:**

I want to generate a dataframe where each row records the function start time, end time and elapsed time.

```
Iteration   image count   Function            start time       end time   elapse time
1           200           collect_vege_images  11.00           11.10       0.10
            200           remove_duplicates    11.10           11.15       0.5
            100 count_veges_in_multiple_plates  11.16          11.20       0.4
2           300           collect_vege_images   11.21          11.31       0.10
            150           remove_duplicates     11.31          11.35       0.5
            50  count_veges_in_multiple_plates  11.35          11.39       0.4
```

**What I have tried so far**

I have written both functions, however, I'm not able to get the desired output that I want. The code is given below as well as the output its generating. Needless to state, I've already looked at similar questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866380/how-can-i-time-a-code-segment-for-testing-performance-with-pythons-timeit?noredirect=1&lq=1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245161/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-functions-automatically-in-python), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66021748/is-there-a-way-to-time-a-block-of-code-that-is-executed-many-times),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47810404/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-python-code), but most are related to timing individual functions only. Looking for a simple solution as I'm beginner in python programming.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import time
    
VEGE_SOURCE = r'\\path to vegetable images'
VEGE_COUNT = 5
VEGE_DST = r'\\path to storing vegetable images'
LOG_FILE_NAME = 'vege_log.csv'
plates = 5
CYCLES=5
counter = ([] for i in range(7))
VEGEID = 'Potato'

def collect_vege_images(VEGE_SOURCE):
    plate = os.listdir(VEGE_SOURCE)

    if len(plate) == 0:
        print("vege source is empty: ", folder)

    else:

        for i in range(VEGE_COUNT):
            vege = plate[0]
            curr_vege = VEGE_SOURCE + '\\' + vege
            shutil.move(curr_vege, VEGE_DST)
            plate.pop(0)
    return

def count_veges_in_multiple_plates(plates):
    N = 0
    for root, dirname, files in os.walk(plates):
        # print(files)
        file_count = len(files)
        vege_img_count += file_count

    return vege_img_count

    
if __name__ == __main__:

    collect_vege_images(VEGE_SOURCE)
    img_count = count_veges_in_multiple_plates(plates=5)


    for i in range(CYCLES):
        print("Round # ", i)
        counter.append(i)
        # print("counter: ", counter)
        start_time = time.process_time()
        collect_vege_images(VEGE_SOURCE)
        count_veges_in_multiple_plates(plates=5)
        end_time = time.process_time()
        elapse_time = round((end_time - start_time), 2)
        fun = collect_vege_images.__name__
        df = pd.DataFrame(
            {'vegeid': VEGEID, 'imgcnt': img_count, 'func': fun, 'start_time': start_time, 'end_time': end_time,
             'elapse_time': elapse_time}, index=[0])
        print(df)
```

**Current code output given below**

```
Round #  1
Moving files...
122 files moved!
iteration  imgcnt   func                    start_time  end_time  elapse_time
   0         122    collect_vege_images     22.10       22.15         0.5
Round #  2
Moving files...
198 files moved!
iteration  imgcnt   func                    start_time  end_time  elapse_time
   1         122    collect_vege_images     22.15       22.19         0.04
```

Comment: This code gives multiple errors, are you sure this is the right one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple decorator to measure start, end and elapsed time and append it to your dataframe.

```python
import pandas as pd
import time

def timeit(func):
    def patched_func(*args, perf_data, **kwargs):
        time_start = time.process_time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        time_end = time.process_time()
        new_row = pd.Series(
            {
                'vegeid': kwargs['vege_id'],
                'imgcnt': kwargs['image_count'],
                'func': func.__name__,
                'start_time': time_start,
                'end_time': time_end,
                'elapse_time': time_end - time_start
            }
        )
        perf_data.append(new_row)
        return result
    return patched_func
    
@timeit
def collect(vege_id, image_count):
    pass
    
@timeit
def remove(vege_id, image_count):
    pass

@timeit
def count(vege_id, image_count):
    pass
    
perf_data = []
for i in range(10):
    collect(vege_id=i, image_count=1 * i, perf_data=perf_data)
    remove(vege_id=i, image_count=10 * i, perf_data=perf_data)
    count(vege_id=i, image_count=100 * i, perf_data=perf_data)
    
print(pd.DataFrame(perf_data))
```

Output:

```
    vegeid  imgcnt     func  start_time   end_time  elapse_time
0        0       0  collect    9.997021   9.997028     0.000007
1        0       0   remove    9.997492   9.997497     0.000005
2        0       0    count    9.997701   9.997704     0.000003
3        1       1  collect    9.997909   9.997914     0.000004
4        1      10   remove    9.998127   9.998130     0.000003
5        1     100    count    9.998308   9.998311     0.000003
```

Some explanation on what's happening here.

`timeit` is a decorator. Decorator is a function that takes another function as an argument, modifies it and returns modified function which then replaces the original one. To use the decorator you use `@` before function declaration:

```python
@my_decorator
def my_function():
    ...
```

which is equivalent of

```python
def my_function():
    ...

my_function = my_decorator(my_function)
```

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-do-i-make-function-decorators-and-chain-them-together/1594484#1594484) if you want to learn more about decorators.

`*args, **kwargs` syntax -- is a way to capture any number of positional (passed without keyword) and keyword arguments. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/552563) to learn more.

Comment: a follow-up question. How to add code execution iteration count as a column in the decorator `timeit()`? Example, say function `collect()` runs multiple times per code execution cycle. I need a column called say `iteration` with a value of `1`. So if function collect executes five times, then iteration column will have value 1 repeated five times. Please advise me if you know how to accomplish this.

Comment: You can add `iteration` parameter the same way I've added `vege_id` parameter. Pass it to the function, then store it in the pd.Series.

Comment: thanks very much for taking the time out to post a response. It worked.